What are the system requirements for Clang?
I'm learning C++ and programming on my phone. This is extremely inconvenient, but I have a laptop, but it’s very weak. I can tell you the characteristics of my laptop.
Intel i3-4005u @ 1.7 GHz
AMD Radeon Graphics and Intel HD Graphics Family
RAM: 4GB
I'm learning C++ to create operating systems, console applications and graphical applications. IDE: VS Code
MSVC++ is too demanding for my laptop because I need Clang. Maybe it won't be so demanding

"I have a laptop, but it’s very weak..." You can use godbolt without having to install anything on your pc. It is an excellent tool/site etc where you can test your programs. You can also use gcc instead of clang. And for learning material there are good c++ books.

Clang for Windows doesn't come with a standard library, so expects MSVC's header files and native libraries to be already installed. You can get that through the Build Tools for Visual Studio without the IDE. Fairly complicated though.

I wrote my master's thesis on a Asus EEEPC with half that memory. you'll be fine. You may want to grab the Embarcadero fork of dev-c++ though.

I've done a lot of C++ programming on a 68030 running at 25 MHz, with 18 MB of RAM.  (I miss my Amiga 3000.)
